# Expiration dates of food items

Tags: storage-lifetime

Is there a general place (database) where I can find expiration dates of food products sold by retailers like Walmart, Albertsons etc?

Comment: are you looking for 'how long cottage cheese lasts after being packaged' question, or 'how do I decode the date code on the bottom of the cup' question?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately expiration dates change frequently, and regularly (or at least they should) as stores change their stock, so there isn't a database that keeps track of that.  If you're looking for a 'shelf life' or how long a product should last after it's production date, a lot of times you can find that information on the manufacturers' websites, or by calling them.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, just got my answer kicked for too few letters, trying again: No there isn't.